# I get the error: " AttributeError: 'Sequential' object has no attribute 'predict_classes' " while coding. Its wrong here

Tags: python, keras

```
def classify(file_path):
  global label_packed
  image = Image.open(file_path)
  image = image.resize((30,30))
  image = numpy.expand_dims(image, axis=0)
  image = numpy.array(image)
  pred = model.predict_classes(image)[0]
  sign = classes[pred+1]
  print(sign)
  label.configure(foreground='#011638', text=sign)
```

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

Change the:

```
model.predict_classes()
```

to

```
model.predict()
```

and it'll return a probability. Then you should define a threshold to consider prediction probabilities to one of the classes. Remember that threshold is up to you. You can be strict about that or not. However, I suppose it to be 0.5:

```
pred_class = np.where(model.predict(example) > 0.5, 1, 0)
```

Then, you'll get predicted classes.

Comment: then i change model. predoct_classes() to model.predict(). I give this:                                          
                 ValueError: Input 0 of layer "sequential_12" is incompatible with the layer: expected shape=(None, 30, 30, 3), found shape=(None, 30, 30, 4)